# Prevent autocomplete of addresses from gmail in android email application

Tags: contacts, samsung-galaxy-s-3, gmail, stock-email-app, auto-correct

I use my Galaxy S3 for both work and personal email messaging. I use gmail for personal and the stock email application, synced to Microsoft Exchange, for work email.

However, when I compose an email in the stock email application, it sometimes autocompletes with an address from gmail.  This is very irritating (and has resulted in some mis-sent emails), and I want to disable it entirely. I do not want to see ANY addresses from my "Gmail Contacts" in the stock email app. I only want to see suggested emails from my Exchange contacts. Possible?

Also, in the meantime I have enabled the "delayed send" feature to remind myself to check email addresses before sending.

Comment: That's a function of the keyboard auto-complete, is it not?

Comment: This question appears to be a duplicate of http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/55271/is-there-a-way-to-have-gmail-autocomplete-to-only-with-gmail-contacts-and-the

Comment: Rather, this is the 'reverse' of that question, but the answer is very likely to be the same for both.

Comment: Yes, that is essentially the same question - no answers though, I notice :(

Answer (score 2):

I had exaclty the same problem. I use Sony Xperia Z with Jelly Bean 4.3

The solution that worked for me is like this:
1. Stop contact autosync of google account. 
2. Clear all data and cache of Contact Storage App.

After this Email app will not autocomplete with Gmail contacts.
 The drawback is that the native Gmail App will not autocomplete either.

In general I believe this should be fixed in the next patch for Android somehow to let me choose from which contacts I want autocomplete to pull.

Hope this helps

KS